# How to detect enum type passed to Enum[]

Tags: c#, enums, ienumerable

In my MVC project I have MyEnum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d
}
```

I also have class:

```
public class MyClass
{    
    public MyEnum SelectType { get; set; }

    public Enum[] NotSupportedTypes{ get; set; }
}
```

In my class for `NotSupportedTypes` I can use **only** `Enum[]` type.

When I'm creating object of class `MyClass` how can I check that in `NotSupportedTypes` only enums of type `MyEnum` are pushed?

```
var model = new MyClass();

//good
model.NotSupportedTypes = new Enum[] { MyEnum.a }

//bad
model.NotSupportedTypes = new Enum[] { SomeOtherEnum.a }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `MyEnum[]` instead of `Enum[]` then?

Comment: Why can you only use `Enum[]`?  That seems like the root of the problem.

Comment: @juharr Technically, even using `MyEnum` wouldn't solve anything... `NotSupportedTypes = new MyEnume[] { (MyEnum)-1 }`

Comment: Because in further code I pass value from `NotSupportedTypes` to `ViewBag.Except` which is used in editor template for different enums. And in editor template someone wrote such check: `var except = (ViewBag.Except as IEnumerable<Enum>)
           ?? (ViewBag.Except is Enum
               ? new Enum[] { ViewBag.Except }
               : new Enum[] { });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check it in the property, for example with `Array.TrueForAll`:

```
private Enum[] _NotSupportedTypes;
public Enum[] NotSupportedTypes
{
    get { return _NotSupportedTypes; }
    set {
        if (!Array.TrueForAll(value, x => x.GetType() == typeof(MyEnum)))
            throw new ArgumentException("All enums must be MyEnum");
        _NotSupportedTypes = value; 
    }
}
```

As mentioned by Xanatos this won't protect you from changes in the array. So you could replace one `MyEnum` in it with a different enum type later. Arrays are not readonly.

So why don't you use a `MyEnum[]` in the first place?

Comment: And even this won't protect from changes to the `NotSupportedTypes`... In C# arrays can't be read only. Nor it will protect against "illegal" MyEnum values.

Answer (score 0):

```
var model = new MyClass();

//good
//model.NotSupportedTypes = new Enum[] { MyEnum.a }

//bad
model.NotSupportedTypes = new Enum[] { SomeOtherEnum.a }

var validTypes = model.NotSupportedTypes.All(n => n.GetType() == typeof(MyEnum));
```